# How to Solve IllegalStateException In android MapView. (Specified Child Already has a parent must cal removeView())?

Tags: android, google-maps, illegalstateexception

I am showing map in custom dialog. first time when i click Showmap button in the dialog map is working fine. but when i click it second time it s crashing. i am creating dialog in fragment. below is the code i have written.

```
expandLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View promptView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //promptView = new View(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (promptView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) promptView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)

                parent.removeView(view);
        }

        try {
            promptView = li.inflate(R.layout.expand_user_location_view, null);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }

         if (mMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.

                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }

            }

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getActivity());

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

    }
});
   private void setUpMap() {


        latLng = new LatLng(latitude , longitude);
        locationzoomWithoutMarker(10, latLng);
    }
  public void locationzoomWithoutMarker(float zoom,LatLng latLng) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mMap.clear();



                LatLng sLatLng = new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(sLatLng)
                        .title("TotalGaz India")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

                mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);


                LatLng cameraLatLng = latLng;
                float cameraZoom = zoom;

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraLatLng, cameraZoom));
        }
```

and my error log here

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call            removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3543)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3519)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:402)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:242)
at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
at com.mobiesprits.yummy_walkins.HomeFragment$8.onClick(HomeFragment.java:467)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17248)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the `promtView` first:

```
   parent.removeView(promptView);
```

instead of:

```
   parent.removeView(view);
```

Comment: @user2199280 Yeah I thought it's just a typo. Glad to help.